# For loop in ExtendScript - keys().forEach not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, xlsx, extendscript

I am working in ExtendScript with bridge to attach labels to documents from an excel document. I am parsing through the excel document using the js-xlsx library. I am running a for loop to parse through the individual cells and get the values, which works perfectly when I run it from the command line. However, when I run it in ExtendScript I am getting an exception that keys().forEach is not a function. Does ExtendScript read for loops differently for some reason? I am having trouble figuring this out. Here is the line that is giving me trouble:

```
var range = {s:{c:0, r:0}, e:{c:1,r:30}};
for (var R = range.s.r; R <= range.e.r; ++R) {
  for (var C = range.s.c; C <= range.e.c; ++C) {
      var cell_address = xls.utils.encode_cell({c:C, r:R});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extendscript, as a language, is stuck at ECMAScript 3 – so it doesn't natively know about `Object.keys()`, nor `Array.forEach()`. Not even `JSON`.

Official mention of this can be found in the [After Effects scripting guide](http://blogs.adobe.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/48/files/2012/06/After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf?file=2012/06/After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf) pag.3, where it says:

> After Effects scripts use the Adobe ExtendScript language, which is an
>   extended form of JavaScript used by several Adobe applications,
>   including Photoshop, Illustrator, and InDesign. ExtendScript
>   implements the JavaScript language according to the ECMA-262
>   specification. The After Effects scripting engine supports the 3rd
>   Edition of the ECMA-262 Standard, including its notational and lexical
>   conventions, types, objects, expressions, and statements. ExtendScript
>   also implements the E4X ECMA-357 specification, which defines access
>   to data in XML format.

The above is not found in the PS scripting guide, nor reference.

If you want to use ES5 features, either include shims, or give [extendscriptr](https://github.com/ExtendScript/extendscriptr) a try. Extendscriptr is a scripting community project (no Adobe involvement) which should let you to write ES5/ES6 code that is then converted to ES3.

Comment: Updated the post. Strangely enough, information about the ECMA compliance is not shared by every app's official scripting documentation.

Comment: The shim file to include in that case: https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim/blob/master/es5-shim.js

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to iterate through dictionary in ExtendScript (works in After Effects at least)

```
var my_dictionary = {};
my_dictionary['fruit'] = "apple";

iterate_through_dict(my_dictionary)

function iterate_through_dict(my_dictionary) {
    for (var i in my_dictionary) {
        alert(my_dictionary[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a for..in loop looks like the best workaround if you only need a key-iteration. I do not want to include a huge file for shimming things I don't need, so the Extendscript code looks more like the examples from Adobe. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out. The error was further down in the file. ExtendScript, or the version I have, does not support forEach loops, so I had to write out the file for the forEach function and import it.

Answer (score 0):

(Though it should be better to post this as a comment to Davide's answer,)

There is an alternative ES5 shim which seems to be more suitable to ExtendScript:
https://github.com/ExtendScript/extendscript-es5-shim/

You can download the all-in-one shim onto a same folder:

```bash
curl -o extendscript-es5-shim.js https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ExtendScript/extendscript-es5-shim/master/index.js
```

and use it as follows:

```
#include "extendscript-es5-shim.js";

// Have a fun with forEach() or any ES5 functions.
```